# Append a column to an existing csv file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv, append

This question has been asked before but those solutions didn't work for me. I have a csv file, `example.csv`, with data in the following format:

```
grid,u,lambda
0.0,0.0,-93000
0.01,-0.01,-93000
0.02,0.05,-93000
```

Now I have a function `f.fraction('function')` which returns me `[1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]`. I want to append this to the same file, `example.csv`. the final result:

```
grid,u,lambda,new_function
0.0,0.0,-93000,1.00000000e+00
0.01,-0.01,-93000,1.00000000e+00
0.02,0.05,-93000,1.00000000e+00
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can read the file first using pandas, append the new column and then save it.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('example.csv')
df['new_function'] = f.fraction('function')
df.to_csv('example.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. This worked perfectly fine. But, if you don't mind can you also provide the solution without using pandas as well, please?. I mean by using import csv.  @diego-ramirez-vasquez

Comment: This post will help you to do it without pandas :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60465764/append-dictionary-or-list-of-values-at-the-end-of-each-row-in-csv-using-python

Comment: Thanks again! @Diego Ramirez Vasquez